# How can I open a tab next to the activeTab from a Safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I want to open a tab using the tabs and windows API, like so...

```
var newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab();
newTab.url = blahURL;
```

...such that the new tab appears next to the currently visible tab. There is a method to do this, but it requires an index. There does not seem to be a way to get the current tab's index. Will I just have to loop through and find the index value of the active tab?

I want to be sure this opens a new tab instead of a window. If I use some JavaScript method to open a new tab, it may open a new window based on user settings, correct?

Comment: Did you ever release this extension? I'm looking for this functionality for safari 8

Comment: Yes! Look for RecoverTabs in Apple's gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the index of the active tab, you can use

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.tabs.indexOf(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab)
```

If you use the `openTab` method of the Safari browser window object, it's guaranteed to open a tab and not a window.